# ADSL Wireless Router Configuration with ethernet(rj45) internet connection

Tags: networking, wireless-router, adsl, rj-45

I have this [adsl wireless router](ftp://support.dlink.co.in/broadband/DSL-2750U/manual/DSL-2750U_C1_Manual_IN_1.00.pdf) but my internet connection only has RJ45 directly connected to my PC. My questions is how can I use my ADSL wireless router with this kind of internet connection.. because I really want to make my connection wireless.. Is it possible? any help please?

Comment: The connection between the modem/router and your PC is Ethernet, not your internet connection - your internet connection is DSL and is the ATM signal between the CO and your modem. That all said, if you already have the PC cabled, why do you want to go wireless? A wired connection is typically more stable and faster than most home wireless setups. If you do insist on going wireless, since your router supports it, just make sure it is turned on in the router and get yourself a wireless adapter as @Lee Taylor mentioned and you're good to go.

Comment: Is that router you linked to currently connected in your setup? or do you just have it lying around?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.

You will need to buy either an internal wireless adapter or an external USB wireless adapter.

A list of wireless dongles from Amazon:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_0_13?url=search-alias%3Dcomputers&field-keywords=wireless+dongle&sprefix=wireless+dong%2Caps%2C235

You haven't given any details of your PC or operating system so it's hard to offer any further advice.

Answer (score 0):

Please visit the below page, i yet to try whether it works or no?

http://www.techtantrik.com/2012/08/mtnl-ftth-optic-fiber-broadband-review.html?m=1

Regards
Raghavendra

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. While the link might provide an answer it can quickly become outdated. Please include the main points from the link in your answer. Thanks.